# How to plot hexbin with dates in matplotlib and pandas?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a hexbin of dates, but there seem to be problems with the approach I take:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getdate():
    return datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(random.randint(0,100))

df=pd.DataFrame([(getdate(), getdate()) for i in range(100)], columns=list("ab"))
plt.hexbin(df.a, df.b)
```

Sometimes there is an error message

```
packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png  formatter: Python int too large to convert to C long
  FormatterWarning, <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x929bba8>
```

In any case, the plot doesn't show up in IPython.

Do you have an idea what's going on and how to get a hexbin plot labeled by dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the date to numbers an use `xaxis_date()` and `yaxis_date()`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl #**added**

def getdate():
    return datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(random.randint(0,100))

df=pd.DataFrame([(getdate(), getdate()) for i in range(10000)], columns=list("ab"))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.hexbin(pl.date2num(df.a), pl.date2num(df.b), gridsize=20)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.yaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.major.formatter.scaled[1.0] = "%Y-%m-%d"
ax.yaxis.major.formatter.scaled[1.0] = "%Y-%m-%d"
pl.xticks(rotation=45);
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, you have three undefined `pl.` in the example, but I corrected that :)