# How do I plot hexbin with Pandas and discrete axes? (alternatively, any color-based plotting)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame like

```
     animal   country  value
0  elephant     India      5
1     camel      Iran      7
2  elephant  Cameroon      1
3     eagle       USA      2
4    turtle      Iran      3
```

I want to be able compare countries across a certain animal, and animals across a certain country easily. I thought the best way to do this is to use x/y axes to represent animal and country, while letting color be the `value` - so I tried a hexbin plot.

When I try

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal': ['elephant', 'camel', 'elephant', 'eagle', 'turtle'],
    'country': ['India', 'Iran', 'Cameroon', 'USA', 'Iran'],
    'value': [5, 7, 1, 2, 3]
})
a.plot(kind = 'hexbin', x = 'animal', y = 'country', C = 'value')
```

I get `KeyError: 'animal'`. But this doesn't happen if I use `value` for `x`, `y`, and `C` - I guess this is because pandas wants numeric values. How do I do this with discrete data (animals/country)?

I thought about assigning each one a number and making a custom axis like [How to plot hexbin with dates in matplotlib and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723906/how-to-plot-hexbin-with-dates-in-matplotlib-and-pandas) suggests, but I felt there might be an easier way. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want a heatmap?

```
import seaborn as sns

a2 = a.pivot_table( index='animal', columns='country', values='value', fill_value=0 )

sns.heatmap(a2)
```

[image]

Btw, as a general recommendation you may also want to store values as categoricals rather than string objects for these sorts of things, although using a `pivot_table` here makes it unnecessary in this particular example.